# Retrieving objects' class from empty list of objects c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a person class with properties ex: name and age, then I created a list of persons in another class which I passed to my 'MainWindow', then I passed my list to a 'UserControl' in constructor.

Here's my Code:

```
- PersonClass:

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }

- PersonCreatorClass:

    PersonClass person1 = new PersonClass();
    PersonClass person2 = new PersonClass();
    public List<object> persons = new List<object>();

    public void AddingPersonsToList()
    {
        person1.Name = "john";
        person1.Age = 21;

        person2.Name = "albert";
        person2.Age = 20;

        persons.Add(person1);
        persons.Add(person2);
    }

- MainWindowClass:

    MainTestClass _mainTestClass = new MainTestClass();
    List<object> data = new List<object>();

    _mainTestClass.AddingPersonsToList();
    data = _mainTestClass.persons;

    DynamicGrid dynamicGrid = new DynamicGrid(data);

- UserControl:

    List<object> _data = new List<object>();

    public DynamicGrid(List<object> data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._data = data;
    }
```

My Question is how can I get the person class (Type) from my list "data" in my user control, my goal is to only send a list of objects to my main window from any class, and get in my user control the type of the object in the list sent.

Nb: Sorry for the display it's just now working in an other way.

Comment: Do you know that you can write `List<PersonClass > _data = new List<PersonClass >();`?

Comment: What happened to using xaml? AFAIK all of this code can be replaced with xaml and `ViewModel`. You would then have access to **ALL** of the data irrespective to what control uses it in UI.

Comment: @XAMlMAX OP mays not be familiar with MVVM yet. It would be better indeed, but you can make it work without.

Comment: @aloisdg of course you can make it work without :-) but then it produces questions like these. ;-) no offence OP.

Comment: Dear  @aloisdg and   @XAMlMAX; 
Here I am using person class and person creator class but my objective is to give my main window any list of objects, and I want to get me it's class, sorry for not specifying earlier.

Comment: @XAMlMAX You have to start somewhere

Comment: @ArnoldDemian Can you add details to your question?

Comment: I am not sure if you mean you want to get objects in the list (in this case Person) to manipulate or extract the information or do you need the actual name of the class (in case you are using reflection somewhere in there)?

Comment: Dear @ XAMlMAX, I put person for testing only, but yes I want to get the type of the class from the objects in the list. I will be more specific and if any changes in my question are required please to inform me.

Comment: I have the 'MainWindow' class that takes a list of object from a custom class, then i send it to my 'UserControl', in my usercontrol I need to extract the class of the objects in my list of objects, but supposing i'm receiving an an empty list, I, to need to have the class, I tried reflection, it gave me that the type is object not the class. Hope it's more specific ?

Comment: To display a list of the classes in your `MainWindow` is very simple, you don't need `UserControl` for that at all! I can get you to the point where you will have the  window displaying the list. Why do you need to get the type of the classes? I have a feeling you just need correct `DataTemplates` for the classes.

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: @XAMlMAX, you are right here I don't need my 'UserControl', but I need the to get to the class properties dynamically, that's why I need the name="ClassName", and FullName = "Namespace.ClassName", of the objects in my list.

Comment: basically it's a reflection problem I know it but the problem is when i do MyList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] I am getting type object not the class.

Comment: _"but I need the to get to the class properties dynamically"_, why do you need to get them?

Comment: I need to put the members of the class in a grid I already done the whole thing i just need to get the class to pass it in that syntax instead of 'PersonClass':  ColumnDynamicBuilder _columnDynamicBuilder = new ColumnDynamicBuilder(typeof(PersonClass));

Comment: Dear @XAMlMAX, thanks for your help but I found that I can't take a list of object in my case i have to take a list of type. thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArnoldDemian you can only `@` notify one user at a time in a message. The second user doesn't get a notification.

Comment: @ArnoldDemian - It would be great if you could show actual C# code in your question. It's a lot of work for someone to recreate your code otherwise.

Comment: @ArnoldDemian - Basically you need to do `public List<PersonClass> persons = new List<PersonClass>();` and your problem instantly goes away.

Comment: Dear @Enigmativity, thanks for your comments I really appreciated, also I think i figure out my problem but I have an other question,should I edit this one to suit my new question or write a different one (which I'm not allowed for 4 days), or maybe in the commentary?

Comment: @ArnoldDemian - You should always try to ask new questions, but if you're blocked (why?) then try asking as a comment. Please don't edit your current question.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks again for your support, here I'm stuck having my 'MainWindow' where I need to pass a list of persons, taking in consideration that it could be a list of anything, the problem is that the element `data` I'm sending in the constructor can not be sent, here's my code:

Comment: `private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadDynamicGrid<PersonClass>();
        }
void LoadDynamicGrid<T>() where T : class
        {
            PersonCreatorClass pcc = new PersonCreatorClass ();
            List<T> data = new List<T>();
            data = pcc.persons as List<T>; // getting the list
 DynamicGrid dynamicGrid = new DynamicGrid(data, extendedControls); // in dynamicGrid constructor i can not define data without knowing the class name
        }`